# Query for max for each year/actor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table as below :

```
Create Table Movies (
    ID int,
    Actor varchar (50),
    MovieName varchar (50),
    ReleaseDate Date
)
```

Let's insert some sample data

```
Insert into Movies (ID,Actor,MovieName, ReleaseDate)
Select 1,'Sean Connery', 'Gone gone wild', '2/1/2014'
Union
Select 2,'Roberta Jones', 'My first love', '2/1/2014'
Union
Select 3,'Michael Young', 'Booba spirit', '2/1/2014'
Union
Select 4,'Sean Conenry', 'Gone gone wild 2', '10/1/2014'
Union
Select 5,'Roberta Jones', 'My Second Love', '2/3/2015'
Union
Select 6,'Michael Young', 'Boboa spirit 2', '2/2/2016'
Union
Select 7,'Sean Connery', 'Gone gone wild 3', '2/1/2015'
Union
Select 8,'Sean Connery', 'Gone gone wild 4', '2/1/2016
```

I would like to know the actor, the release date and number of movies for each actor during each year but only return the year with the biggest number of movies.

Here's a query that works fine on SQL Server

```
Select * from Movies

select Actor, Release, NbrMovies
From (Select Actor, Release, NbrMovies, rank() over (partition by Actor Order By NbrMovies desc) as rn 
      From (Select Actor, year(ReleaseDate) as Release, count(*) as NbrMovies
            From Movies
            Group by Actor, year(ReleaseDate)
           ) x 
     ) y
where rn = 1
```

I would like to know if there is a way to write the query without any window function like rank() or row_number() because I'm use it as well for Oracle.

Thanks

Comment: Oracle supports both `rank()` and `row_number()`, so your query should work there too.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine for both SQL Server and Oracle.  However, you can remove one layer of subqueries:

```
select Actor, ReleaseYear, NbrMovies
from (Select Actor, year(ReleaseDate) as ReleaseYear,   
             count(*) as NbrMovies,
             rank() over (partition by Actor Order By count(*) desc) as rn 
      From Movies m
      Group by Actor, year(ReleaseDate)
     ) m 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: How would you write a Having filter of the group by for max count?

Comment: That is unnecessary.  This query runs in both Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: I understand but I was trying to figure if that was a possibility to use a filter that way before ever getting to the rank windowing aggregate; thereby not needing to make that into a subquery.